# Multiple start scripts using Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a working Maven build (shown below) that prepares a couple of executables to launch as two separate processes.

Although this works fine, how can this be done using Gradle? I see that Gradle provides a plugin called `application`, but I have a hard time finding a nice example on how to tell it that when typing: `gradle stage`, it should create 2 executables.

Right now when I call `stage` it only provides an executable on the "root" mainclass defined in my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'SpringLauncher'
applicationName = 'foo'
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

task stage(dependsOn: ['clean', 'installApp', 'hello'])
```

And the Maven build:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <configuration> 
        <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory> 
        <programs>
            <program>
                <mainClass>foo.bar.scheduler.SchedulerMain</mainClass>
                <name>scheduler</name>
            </program>
            <program>
                <mainClass>SpringLauncher</mainClass>
                <name>web</name>
            </program>
        </programs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <phase>package</phase><goals><goal>assemble</goal></goals>
          </execution>            
      </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately the gradle application plugin does not provide first class support for multiple executable scripts.

Luckily though, because gradle scripts are groovy, you can change what the application plugin does reasonably easily.

The [documentation for the Application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) show that the `startScripts` task is of type [CreateStartScripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html), so try creating yourself a second task of the same type

```
task schedulerScripts(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    mainClassName = "foo.bar.scheduler.SchedulerMain"
    applicationName = "scheduler" 
    outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'scripts')
    classpath = jar.outputs.files + project.configurations.runtime
}
```

then include the output of that task in your distribution

```
applicationDistribution.into("bin") {
            from(schedulerScripts)
            fileMode = 0755
}
```

Comment: Adding `duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'` to the copy task will eliminate the duplicate scripts inside the `bin/` directory.

Comment: Dead link for CreateStartScripts. It's here now: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html

Answer (score 3):

It might be better to use `JavaExec`

```
task scheduler(type: JavaExec) {
   main = "foo.bar.scheduler.SchedulerMain"
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

task web(type: JavaExec) {
   main = "SpringLauncher"
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

You can then run `gradle scheduler web`

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin DSL

### Reusable Function

The equivalent of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252340/430128) using Gradle Kotlin DSL, and additionally abstracting out the common logic for creating multiple scripts into a re-usable function:

```kotlin
fun createAdditionalScript(name: String, configureStartScripts: CreateStartScripts.() -> Unit) =
  tasks.register<CreateStartScripts>("startScripts$name") {
    configureStartScripts()
    applicationName = name
    outputDir = File(project.buildDir, "scripts")
    classpath = tasks.getByName("jar").outputs.files + configurations.runtimeClasspath.get()
  }.also {
    application.applicationDistribution.into("bin") {
      from(it)
      fileMode = 0b000_111_101_101
      duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    }
  }
```

and now you can use it like this:

```
createAdditionalScript("foo") {
  mainClassName = "path.to.FooKt"
}

createAdditionalScript("bar") {
  mainClassName = "path.to.BarKt"
}
```

### Reusability via `buildSrc`

The function `createAdditionalScript` is better placed in `buildSrc` or plugin to keep the main script clean, and to do that, it would look like this:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.file.DuplicatesStrategy
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaApplication
import org.gradle.api.tasks.application.CreateStartScripts
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.configure
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.register
import java.io.File

fun Project.createAdditionalScript(name: String, configureStartScripts: CreateStartScripts.() -> Unit) =
  tasks.register<CreateStartScripts>("startScripts$name") {
    configureStartScripts()
    applicationName = name
    outputDir = File(buildDir, "scripts")
    classpath = tasks.getByName("jar").outputs.files + configurations.getByName("runtimeClasspath")
  }.also {
    configure<JavaApplication> {
      applicationDistribution.into("bin") {
        from(it)
        fileMode = 0b000_111_101_101
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
      }
    }
  }
```

Note the `fileMode` uses the binary permissions representation to set the r, w, and x bits for user, group, and other. The Kotlin DSL doesn't interpret values like `0755` as octal like Groovy does.

Answer (score 0):

The simples approach I found was adding a new `CreateStartScripts` task and making it a dependency of `schedulerScripts`:

```
task schedulerScripts(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    mainClassName = 'foo.bar.scheduler.SchedulerMain'
    applicationName = 'scheduler'
    classpath = startScripts.classpath
    outputDir = startScripts.outputDir
}
startScripts.dependsOn schedulerScripts
```