# Clearly separating multiple applications as subprojects with common dependency and joint source

Tags: gradle

I've found Gradle's multiple projects documentation confusing and unhelpful about where the source and output of projects in a multi-project setup will reside.

I'd like to see a concrete example with Java and the `application` plugin rather than just tasks that write to standard out.

I'm trying to build 2 to 4 java applications that share a few common classes but have different main classes. I've seen a few ways to do this in one project [EG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421857/is-it-possible-to-specify-multiple-main-classes-using-gradle-application-plugi) where you use the `application` plugin but disable the scripts' defaults then create custom tasks for each application. I was hoping there might be a simpler to maintain way to accomplish this with subprojects such that:

1. All source is still in one `~<project>/src/java/{main,test}/pkg/name/` tree
2. The applications are subprojects referring to the root projects' source
3. The build and distInstall tasks build and install all the applications.

E.G. Looking at the ([documented](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)) [example](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/userguide/multiproject/addTropical/water),

I wished to be able to have it structured like:

```
water/
  build.gradle (uses plugin java, builds main and test sourcesets)
  whale/
    build.gradle (uses plugin application for whale.WhaleApp, depends on water proj)
  krill/
    build.gradle (uses plugin application for krill.KrillApp, depends on water proj)
  src/
    java/
      main/<namespace>/
        common/
          Water.java (common utils)
          Life.java (a base class for Whale etc)
        whale/
          WhaleApp.java (main cmd line for Whales)
          Whale.java (extends Life)
        krill/
          KrillApp.java (main cmd line for Krill)
          Krill.java (extends Life)
      test/<namespace>/
        common/
          *Test.java
        whale/
          *Test.java
        krill/
          *Test.java
```

Comment: The folder structure in your question is a bit confusing. Can you try to use an ascii tree instead? Something like this: http://i.imgur.com/DAsE41m.png You can generate that from an existing folder structure using the `tree` command on both linux and windows btw.

Comment: @RaGe You'll see very similar diagrams in the Gradle documentation, I think it's actually clearer than breaking out a new line for every single directory, but I've made it match Gradle doc style even more. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: Your edit definitely helps. How strong is your "all source under 1 src/java" requirement? Typically each module's code lives in its own src/java folder. What you're asking can still be done, but it's a big departure from gradle's opinionated way, and makes the build scripts convoluted.

Comment: If anyone wonders, the 1 /src/java with main|test was important for this project (not about whales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a bit of trial and error, but if it benefits anyone else to know I did solve this with my constraints by doing the following file setup (analogously to my question's layout (wherein the important settings.gradle files weren't mentioned)) then the basically working setup looked like:

### Structure

```
water/
  settings.gradle
  build.gradle
  whale/
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
  krill/
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
  src/
    java/
      main/<namespace>/
        common/
          Water.java
          Life.java
        whale/
          WhaleApp.java
          Whale.java
        krill/
          KrillApp.java
          Krill.java
      test/<namespace>/
        common/
          *Test.java
        whale/
          *Test.java
        krill/
          *Test.java
```

With contents of these files looking like:

#### water/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'water'
include 'whale', 'krill'
```

#### water/build.gradle

```
group 'oceanGroup'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets {
  main { java { srcDir 'src/java/main' }}
  test { java { srcDir 'src/java/test' }}
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
     testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

#### whale/settings.gradle

```
$task.name = 'whale'
```

#### whale/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = '<namespace>.whale.WhaleApp'

dependencies {
    compile project(rootProject.path)
    runtime project(rootProject.path)
}
```

#### krill/settings.gradle

```
$task.name = 'krill'
```

#### krill/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = '<namespace>.krill.KrillApp'

dependencies {
    compile project(rootProject.path)
    runtime project(rootProject.path)
}
```

Now, if you issue `gradle installDist` it'll make a `build/install/$task.name/bin/$task.name` script *in each subproject* that you can use to run the right main class in the jar copied to the `lib` directory. If you only `assemble` you will get the right jar, and scripts in `build/scripts` but they'll be unable to run without the jar on the classpath or something like that.

Thinking it over though, I wonder if the "multi-project" setup couldn't be entirely configured from a single `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` set within `water` defining the sub-projects' tasks AND settings and pointing the application plugin to output to the root project's build directory.